# Type Error: Cannot read the property of the undefined - React Js Web Api

Tags: reactjs

I am creating application that will fetch data from web api and display the result in ag grid. I have created one sample web api project which will return list objects.Trying to display the output of the web api to ag grid. But not able to see any data in grid. Can you tell me what may be wrong in the below source code.

**Below the output from web api.**

```
<ArrayOfProject xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TeamsApp.Models">
<Project>
<Description>Electrical Work</Description>
<Duration>8</Duration>
<Hours>300</Hours>
<TaskId>2.1</TaskId>
<TaskName>Main electric panel</TaskName>
<Weightage>2</Weightage>
</Project>
</ArrayOfProject>
```

**Below the source code for react js.**

```
import { PaneDirective, PanesDirective, SplitterComponent } from 


'@syncfusion/ej2-react-layouts';

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {AgGridColumn, AgGridReact} from 'ag-grid-react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import { GridApi, RefSelector } from 'ag-grid-community';
import axios from 'axios';


//const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(InitialRowData);
class FirstTab extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          columnDefs: [
              {headerName: "TaskId", field: "TaskId"},
              {headerName: "TaskName", field: "Taskname"},
              {headerName: "Duration", field: "Duration"},
              {headerName: "Hours", field: "Hours"},
              {headerName: "Weightage", field: "Weightage"},
              {headerName: "Description", field: "Description"}
          ],
          rowData: [
              //{TaskId: "Toyota", TaskName: "Celica", Duration: 35000, Hours: 8,Weightage: 3,Description: "Test"}
             
          ]
      }
        this.Rightpane = this.Rightpane.bind(this);
    }
    //const [rowData, setRowData]= useState(InitialRowData);
     componentDidMount(){
      fetch("http://localhost:64155/api/Project").then(res =>{ console.log(res);
        // if(!res.ok){
        //   throw Error("Failed check")
        // }
         return res.json();
     })
      .then(
        rowData => {
          this.setState({
            rowData
          })
         
         
        }
      )
      console.log(this.state.rowData);
      }  
      
    
    Rightpane(){
     
       
   //render(){  
   //console.log(this.state.employees);
   //const taskList =[this.state.employees.map(task=>task.TaskId),this.state.employees.map(task=>task.TaskName)]   ;  
   return (
         <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height:1000 , width: 1500}}>
            <AgGridReact defaultColDef={{sortable: true, filter: true,editable: true }}
                pagination={true}
                columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                rowData={this.state.rowData}
                >
              
            </AgGridReact>
       </div>
   )
   
}
render() {
    return (<div className="App">
<SplitterComponent id="horizontal" height="250px" width='1900px'>
<PanesDirective>

<PaneDirective size='200px' content={this.Rightpane}/>
</PanesDirective>
</SplitterComponent>
</div>);
}
}
    
export default FirstTab;
```

Comment: What specifically is producing the error?  Which value is `undefined` and what property are you trying to read on that value?  Also, please use consistent indentation to format code for readability.  This will make it easier for us *and you* to read and understand the code.

Comment: I am trying to display a array field in the table structure. Value for the array field will be fetched from web api using fetch method.  This error is throwing when trying to iterate the array field using map function. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state').

Comment: Also I have split the screen into two components. Table structure code will be in Right pane directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is on `projects` initialization.
Not only but since you use `this.state` in a function, you have to bind that function in `constructor`. So:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      projects: []
    };
    this.Rightpane = this.Rightpane.bind(this);
}
```

**EDIT**:
If you want to display rows dynmically in `AgGridReact`, as explained [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update-row-data/) you have to:

1. define a function to manage `onGridReady` event;
2. call `setRowData` every time you update grid's row.

So your code should be refactor because `fetch` should be moved from `componentDidMount` to `onGridReady` event and then instead of use `this.setState` we can use `setRowData` to update rows.

So your code becomes:

```
class FirstTab extends React.Component{
     //constructor still the same

     onGridReady(params){
        this.gridApi = params.api;
        fetch("http://localhost:64155/api/Project").then(res => { 
              console.log(res);
              return res.json();
        }).then(rowData => {
              //this.setState({ rowData }); no more this but...
              this.gridApi.setRowData(rowData);
        })
      }

      Rightpane(){
         return (
            <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height:1000 , width: 1500}}>
               <AgGridReact 
                  defaultColDef={{sortable: true, filter: true,editable: true }}
                  pagination={true}
                  columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                  rowData={this.state.rowData}
                  onGridReady={this.onGridReady}> //here the binding with onGridReady function
                </AgGridReact>
              </div>
       )}  

       //render function still the same
}
```

Comment: I tried this also. But its throwing the same error.

Comment: @GirishS I forgot to mention state binding. I updated ny answer.

Comment: Error got resolved. But when I tried to display the array objects in ag grid react  its showing empty grid. Can u tell me what may be the reason.

Comment: @GirishS so now you changed your code and want to display `projects` in `AgGridReact` correct? If yes, could you update your question adding new code? just relevant part (`AgGridReact` should be enought)

Comment: I have edited the question and added new code.

Comment: @GirishS hey I updated my answer. If you use `AgGridReact ` I understood that you have to refactor your code a little bit...

Comment: @GirishS No problem. Have a nice day =)

Comment: Hi Giovanni... I need to add a new row in ag grid on button click. As i am new to react i am facing difficulty in solving this issues. I already posted a seperate thread for this and it have code in it. Can u tell me what is the issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71778466/trying-to-add-a-new-row-to-ag-grid-but-row-not-adding