# Trying to add a new row to ag-grid - But row not adding

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a new row to the ag- grid but its not adding. I have used gridAPI.updateRowData method to create new row in ag-grid. I have created one function for creating new rows in ag-grid. I have called this function on button click events. But row is not adding when i click new button. Please suggest a solution.

**Below is the source code.**

```
import { PaneDirective, PanesDirective, SplitterComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-

layouts';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {AgGridColumn, AgGridReact} from 'ag-grid-react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import { GridApi, RefSelector } from 'ag-grid-community';
import axios from 'axios';
    
class FirstTab extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          columnDefs: [
              {headerName: "TaskId", field: "TaskId"},
              {headerName: "TaskName", field: "TaskName"},
              {headerName: "Duration", field: "Duration"},
              {headerName: "Hours", field: "Hours"},
              {headerName: "Weightage", field: "Weightage"},
              {headerName: "Description", field: "Description"}
          ],
          rowData: [
            
             
          ]
      }
        this.Rightpane = this.Rightpane.bind(this);
        this.Leftpane = this.Leftpane.bind(this);
        this.onAddRows = this.onAddRows.bind(this);
       
    }
    onGridReady(params){
      this.gridApi = params.api;
      fetch("http://localhost:64155/api/Project").then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            return res.json();
      }).then(rowData => {
            //this.setState({ rowData }); no more this but...
            this.gridApi.setRowData(rowData);
      })
    }

    onAddRows() {
     
      this.gridApi.updateRowData({
        add: [{TaskId: "", TaskName: "", Duration: 0, Hours: 0,Weightage: 0,Description: ""}]
           });
           
          }
            
    Rightpane(){
          
   return (
   
         <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height:1000 , width: 1500}}>
           
           <button className="btn btn-primary mb-3" 
            onClick={this.onAddRow}>New</button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button className="btn btn-primary mb-3">Delete</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button className="btn btn-primary mb-3">Move up</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button className="btn btn-primary mb-3">Move down</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <AgGridReact defaultColDef={{sortable: true, filter: true,editable: true }}
                pagination={true}
                onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
                columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                  rowData={this.state.rowData}>
                          
            </AgGridReact>
       </div>
   )
   
}
render() {
    return (<div className="App">
<SplitterComponent id="horizontal" height="250px" width='1900px'>
<PanesDirective>
//<PaneDirective size='200px' content={this.Leftpane}/>
<PaneDirective size='200px' content={this.Rightpane}/>
</PanesDirective>
</SplitterComponent>
</div>);
}
}
 
export default FirstTab;
```

Comment: Can anyone give me a suggestion for the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new blank row using the predefined columnDefs of the grid.

```
gridApi.applyTransaction({ add: [{}] });
```

an example calling this in React/TS from button click

```
function addNewRow(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) {
    if (gridApi) {
      gridApi.applyTransaction({ add: [{}] });
    }
  }
```

reference: https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update-transactions/